# In Flutter app anyone can tell me How can I display a pdf file in one screen as horizontal scrolling?

Tags: flutter, pdf, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

**flutter developer**. Anyone can tell me how can I **display the complete pdf file in one screen** as **horizontal scrolling**. I want in my application the display the **complete pdf file in the horizontal scroll page by page**. But I don't understand how can I do this in the flutter app. If **anyone** can do this before, please **share the flutter code** that how I am solving my this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some plugins available to view a pdf file , some are mentioned below ...

[1. advance pdf viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/advance_pdf_viewer)

[2. Flutter pdf viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdf_viewer)

Comment: thanks for reponse. But i am used simply pdf package and find the solution by this package.

Comment: hey which package did u use?